# How to fix 'unpack require a buffer of 8 bytes' error when handling 8 bytes?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, struct, binary

I wrote a client that connects to a server written in Go. Then I send an 8 byte packet. As the response comes in, it gets passed through a function I built for unpacking it - which generates an error:

> Error:    line 38, in binary_response
> tag, code = struct.unpack('!I I ', response[:8])   struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 8 bytes

I've tried to take out the function and do everything in the `while` loop, but have the same error.

```
            import socket
            import struct
            import textwrap
            from time import sleep
            
            TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
            TCP_PORT = 4200
            
            TAB_1 = '\t - '
            TAB_2 = '\t\t - '
            TAB_3 = '\t\t\t - '
            TAB_4 = '\t\t\t\t - '
            
            DATA_TAB_1 = '\t   '
            DATA_TAB_2 = '\t\t   '
            DATA_TAB_3 = '\t\t\t   '
            DATA_TAB_4 = '\t\t\t\t   '
            
            def main():
                s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                s.connect(("127.0.0.1", 4200))
            
                packet = struct.pack('!ii', 10, 4)
            
                s.send(packet)
            
                while True:
                    response = s.recv(65535)
                    bny = binary_response(response)
                    print(TAB_1 + 'Binary Response Segment:')
                    print('Response Code: ', bny[1])
                    print('Client ID: ', bny[0])
                    print('Message: ', response.decode('latin-1'))
            
            
            # Unpack binary_response
            def binary_response(response):
                tag, code = struct.unpack('!I I ', response[:8])
                return tag, code
            
            
            main()
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the size of the data that is actually received (from `response = s.recv(65535)`)? It's pretty clear that there are fewer bytes than you thought. Just because you add the `[:8]` slice notation does not mean there are 8 bytes in the buffer -- that only *limits* the size to a maximum of 8.

Comment: So when I ran :  print(response.__sizeof__()) I got 89, which I'm assuming is the amount of bytes. How would I unpack the data without getting that error knowing that information. Also if I run  print(bny.__sizeof__()) 48. I dont know if that would be helpful

Comment: Use `len(response)`. The `__sizeof__` method provides the internal data structure size which is of no interest here. You just want the length of the byte string in the response buffer.